# Drupal Menu in WordPress blog

Tags: wordpress, menu, drupal-7

Hi i have a question.
I am develop a website that uses Drupal 7 as CMS and WordPress as blog, and i have a little problem, how to made the menu be avaible to both blog and site.
Any idea or suggestion

Thanks

Comment: Drupal and WordPress are both considered CMSes (Content Management Systems), and as such, I would personally not recommend combining them. WordPress has the capability to run itself as a full website (not just a blog), and Drupal has the capability to act as a blog (without the use of WordPress), so personally, I would re-evaluate your approach.

Comment: the client want it, this way, i think the same way your do

Comment: This is why I don't let clients make decisions like this, because they never know what they're talking about. :P

Answer (score 0):

I'm about to roll up my sleeves and do this myself. I'm planning to use Drupal's Services module to serve up the contents of the primary-links menu from Drupal and I'm writing a WP plugin to sync that data in to a menu in WordPress.